# How would one go about to create or display an image from MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and trying to figure out it works. I'm just experimenting with simple projects, and there are somethings that are unclear.

Let's say I want to load an image depending on value (true or false from a checkbutton) from my controller. I have no problem with recieving the value from my view but how would I go in **generating** this html element?

A few ideas that comes to mind is.

- Use `IsVisible=false` attribute on already rendered image element and then just change that attribute with CSS
- Use `ViewBag` to send data between `View` and `Controller`
- Use `Html.Helper` to create a "personalized" element.

What is the way to go in creating element from a Controller and pass it to a View regarding "Best-pratice" ?

Comment: Just build a string of the source `<img src="@Model.src"/>`. Unless you want to stream it form a backend resource?

Comment: But what if I want to create the html from the controller?

Comment: **Don't**, you never (mostly) create HTML in the controller. The views job is rendering the controllers job is logic/routing

Comment: Ah okey so all the html element needs to be in the View code otherwise I can't display E.G an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it like this:

### View model/model

```
public class viewModel
{
    public string imgSrc {get; set;}
}
```

### Controller

```
public class myController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult myAction()
    {
       bool switch;
       viewModel vm = new viewModel();
       if (switch)
            vm.Src = "something.jpg";
       else
            vm.Src = "somthingelse.jpg";
       return View(vm);
    }

}
```

### Razor

```
@model viewMoel

<img src="@Model.Src"/>
```

MVC is based on seperation of concerns. Read about the [design pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really). People often think MVC is a technology, it's not, it's a pattern.

As such it should be used correctly with the correct parts doing what they are designed to do. So just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should. In MVC the views job (concern) is rendering the content. The controller should have no knowledge of this content. It's job is routing and generating of the Model. So all you HTML should be in the view (full stop)